# python chinese character not writing to file correctly…..with some programs

Tags: python, macos, dictionary, character-encoding, chinese-locale

So I've been working with the CC-CEDICT, a free downloadable Chinese-English dictionary. I've been using python to make some small changes and reformat the dictionary. When I ran code that just reorganized the dictionary as a csv file, I had no issues and the characters were written into the file as expected. Here is the code for that:

```
filename = 'cedict_ts.u8.txt'
newname = 'cedict_ts.u8.csv'

f = open(filename,'r')
allLines = f.readlines()
f.close()

newf = open(newname, 'w')
endofhash = False
for i in range(0, len(allLines)):
 curLine = allLines[i]
 if curLine[0] == '#':
     newf.write(curLine)
 else:
     if(not endofhash):
        newarr = ['Traditional','Simplified','Pinyin','Definition(s)\r\n']
        newline = ','.join(newarr)
        newf.write(newline)
        endofhash = True

    firstws = curLine.find(' ')
    lsbrack = curLine.find('[')
    rsbrack = curLine.find(']')
    fslash = curLine.find('/')
    lslash = curLine.rfind('/')
    trad = curLine[0:firstws]
    simp = curLine[firstws+1:lsbrack-1]
    piny = curLine[lsbrack+1:rsbrack]
    defin = curLine[fslash+1:lslash]
    defin = defin.replace('/','; ')
    defin = defin + '\r\n'
    newarr = [trad, simp, piny, defin]
    newline = ','.join(newarr)
    newf.write(newline)

newf.close()
```

However, when I run a program that also changes the pinyin system and adds it to the dictionary, the content of the text file is gobbly-gook. But, as a test I had the program print out each line before it was written to the text file, and it prints to the terminal as expected. Here is the code that does that:

```
from pinyinConverter import *

filename = 'cedict_ts.u8.txt'
newname = 'cedict_ts_wpym.u8.csv'

f = open(filename,'r')
allLines = f.readlines()
f.close()

apy = readPinyinTextfile('pinyinchars.txt')

newf = open(newname, 'w')
endofhash = False
for i in range(0, len(allLines)):
    curLine = allLines[i]
    if curLine[0] == '#':
        newf.write(curLine)
    else:
        if(not endofhash):
            newarr = ['Traditional','Simplified','Pinyin','PinyinWithMarks','Definition(s)\r\n']
            newline = ','.join(newarr)
            newf.write(newline)
            endofhash = True

        firstws = curLine.find(' ')
        lsbrack = curLine.find('[')
        rsbrack = curLine.find(']')
        fslash = curLine.find('/')
        lslash = curLine.rfind('/')
        trad = curLine[0:firstws]
        simp = curLine[firstws+1:lsbrack-1]
        piny = curLine[lsbrack+1:rsbrack]
        split_piny = piny.split(' ')
        for i in range(0, len(split_piny)):
            curPin = split_piny[i]
            newPin = convertPinyinSystem(curPin, apy)
            split_piny[i] = newPin
        pnwm = ' '.join(split_piny)
        defin = curLine[fslash+1:lslash]
        defin = defin.replace('/','; ')
        defin = defin + '\r\n'
        newarr = [trad, simp, piny, pnwm, defin]
        newline = ','.join(newarr)
        newf.write(newline)

newf.close()
```

And here is the pinyinConverter file code:

```
def convertPinyinSystem(inputString, allPinyin):

    chars = ['a','e', 'i', 'o','u','u:']

    tone = grabTone(inputString)
    toneIdx = (tone - 1) * 2
    hasIdx = -1
    for i in range(0, len(chars)):
        if(chars[i] in inputString):
            hasIdx = i
    newString = inputString
    newString = newString.replace(str(tone),'')
    if(not ('iu' in inputString)):
        newChar = allPinyin[hasIdx][toneIdx:toneIdx+2]
    else:
        newChar = allPinyin[4][toneIdx:toneIdx+2]

    newString = newString.replace(chars[hasIdx],newChar)
    if(tone == 5):
        newString = inputString
        newString = newString.replace(str(tone),'')
        return newString
    elif(tone == -1):
        return inputString
    else:
        return newString




def readPinyinTextfile(pinyintextfile):
    f = open(pinyintextfile, 'r')
    allLines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    for i in range(0, len(allLines)):
        curLine = allLines[i]
        curLine = curLine[0:len(curLine)-1]
        allLines[i] = curLine

    return allLines



def grabTone(inputText):

    isToneIdx = False
    idx = 0
    while(not isToneIdx):
        isToneIdx = is_int(inputText[idx])
        if(isToneIdx):
            break
        else:
            idx += 1
            if(idx == len(inputText)):
                return -1

    return int(inputText[idx])


def is_int(s):
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

And the content of the pinyin chars.txt file is this:

```
āáăà
ēéĕè
īíĭì
ōóŏò
ūúŭù
ǖǘǚǜ
```

I'm on a 2009 MacBook Pro, running OSX version 10.8.5, python is version 2.7.6 and the coding of the dictionary is UTF-8. Also I know some of the code for doing the pinyin conversion is not optimized, but for this it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pinyin file is encoded as utf-8, you might want to try using the [codecs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) package, which is part of the standard library, like this:

```
import codecs

...

def readPinyinTextfile(pinyintextfile):
    f = codecs.open(pinyintextfile, 'r', 'utf-8')
```

If it looks okay in the terminal, then it's likely that you need to specifically change the writing function to use the codecs package:

```
apy = readPinyinTextfile('pinyinchars.txt')

newf = codecs.open(newname, 'w', 'utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick, I wasn't aware of the extra considerations that need to be taken into account when working with UTF-8, I'll keep that in mind! What was happening was that I was mixing UTF-8 encoded strings with ASCII encoded strings, so python interpreted all the strings as ASCII strings when writing to file. Making sure all strings were encoded as UTF-8 worked.